# How to sort a data table if we are using <t:columns> in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I am studying tomahawk, I just want to know if I generate a datatable using `<t:columns>` then how to sort the dataTable on the click on the header of that particular column, like we are using `<t:commandSortHeader>` in normal `<t:column>` attribute. Kindly Help.

Answer (score 2):

Using a t:datatable you don't really need the t:commandSortHeader, unless you want to customise what property it uses to sort.

Here is what you need to get this working:

```
<h:form>
<t:dataTable
    id="data"
    value="#{BACKINGBEAN.DATA}"
    var="item"
    sortColumn="#{BACKINGBEAN.sortColumn}"
            sortAscending="#{BACKINGBEAN.sortAscending}">
```

...

```
<t:column defaultSorted="true" sortable="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="header text"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.property}" />
</t:column>
```

...

```
</t:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Then in your backing bean:

```
private String sortColumn;
private boolean sortAscending;
```

with default getters/setters/lombok. They are just so the tag can set data.

This is a great reference:
http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Working_with_auto_sortable_tables

But it misses the discussion about the backing bean properties, plus that it needs to be wrapped in a `<h:form>` even if you dont have any form elements.

Comment: The apache-wiki also does not mention this won't work when your bean is `@RequestScoped`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use jQuery plugin sort. Look [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

The other is to use **t:dataTable** together with **t:commandSortHeader** as you have described

```
<t:dataTable  
id="data"  
value="#{BACKINGBEAN.DATA}"  
var="item"  
...  
sortable="true"
rows="10">
```

Comment: thanks for the for telling the possiblity in jQuery ,but wanted to try without it, my doubt is like even when if if put <t:commandSortHeader> within the <t:columns> its getting sorted according to the first column only, and not with respective of individual column.

Comment: Yes are you right.
You will need to do this on the SQL side before you retrieve the list is my guess. You need to `order by some1 some2`