# How to sort a data table if we are using <t:columns> in JSF 1.1?

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

i am aware that there is a question that is almost exactly like the one im asking here, but since i cant comment yet i have to "reopen" it here.

this is the original question:
[How to sort a data table if we are using <t:columns> in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522341/how-to-sort-a-data-table-if-we-are-using-tcolumns-in-jsf)

my question to the first answer, first comment is:
why is it apparently impossible to have a request based bean for sorting with tomahawk as stated in the comment?

wouldnt the "view" just sort it every time it gets loaded/reloaed, whats the harm in having it sort more than once?
assuming a "small dataset" theres not a big performance impact.

Comment: Theoretically, it shouldn't matter the bean to be request scoped. The only issue here is that, if you're loading data on bean initialization, it would get reloaded once and again for each request, with might result in bad performance. Still, you could give it a try.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, thats what i thought. the comment just sounded like its impossible. could you make that comment a answer?

Comment: I don't think it is impossible, just that it should work. It's been a (long) while since I  don't use JSF 1.1, that's why I tell you to give it a try. You can't rely on a single comment without any references.